# Global Dilemma - storing values from db that rarely change

Tags: php, database-design

I am not sure how to approach this in a way that would make the web app run efficiently.  I am concerned about properly implementing this because I am working with a high traffic website.

I have 3 tables in a `MySQL` DB, the values in these tables rarely change but are referenced quite a bit.  What would be the best way to store and access that data in `PHP`?

Table examples:

```
GENRES   
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | is_active | name      | content_limit | thumbnail    | thumbnail_active    |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 | ☺         | Animals   |            65 | Animals.png  | Animals_Active.png  |
|  2 | ☺         | Art       |            30 | Art.png      | Art_Active.png      |
|  3 |           | Biography |             0 | NULL         | NULL                |
|  4 | ☺         | Children  |            50 | Children.png | Children_Active.png |
|  6 | ☺         | Fantasy   |            15 | Fantasy.png  | Fantasy_Active.png  |
|  7 |           | Fiction   |             0 | NULL         | NULL                |
|  8 |           | Health    |             0 | NULL         | NULL                |
| 10 |           | Music     |             0 | Music.png    | Music_Active.png    |
| 11 |           | Politics  |             0 | NULL         | NULL                |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

```
SERVERS
+----+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| id | is_active | name  | url                        | webserver_document_root | description |
+----+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|  1 | ☺         | name1 | http://server1.website.com | /dir1                   |  NULL       |
|  2 | ☺         | name2 | http://server1.website.com | /dir2                   |  NULL       |
+----+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What options are you thinking of? Do you have any code?

Comment: Originally I just had a class for each table that checks if data has already been set/retrieved, but with over 5K users accessing this a few times a minute still makes it heavy.

Comment: What kind of code is executed when users access your site? It's hard to give feedback without code.(How are the db accessed)

Comment: There is no special code that verifies the users because this data needs to be accessed regardless of the person/user looking at webpage is logged in or not.  Let's say when a person goes to the home page I need to utilize data from the two tables, but I'd rather not have to query the tables every time I need that data because it rarely ever changes.

Comment: Ok- are you using persistant db-connection?

Comment: Caching? Could that be an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the DB all the time can be pretty expensive.

Recent PHP distributions come with [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) installed. APC is very efficient. APC stores data indexed with a *key* in shared memory (thus accessible from all forked PHP processes).

You have to tell APC (in options of `apc.ini`) how many MB or GB you want to reserve.

Then you can store and retrieve values very quickly.

E.g. you could store values for

```
1 | ☺         | Animals   |            65 | Animals.png  | Animals_Active.png
```

as

```
'1:1:Animals:65:Animals.png:Animals_Active.png'
```

like

```
apc_store("key1", '1:1:Animals:65:Animals.png:Animals_Active.png');
```

or make an initialization PHP to load *once* from the database all rows and store them in APC.
Then, to retrieve data from 'key1'

```
$arr = explode(':', apc_fetch("key1"));
```

in array `$arr`.
In this example, the key from the DB is `1`. So you could name the APC key `key1` ...
Retrieving a bunch of data (eg keys from 0 to 9)

```
$alldata = array();

for ($key=0 ; $key<9 ; $key++) {
   $arr = explode(':', apc_fetch("key$key"));
   // process that row if necessary
   $alldata[] = $arr;
}
```

You can then use a line of data thanks to

```
$alldata[ $somekey ]
```

and an element from that row

```
$alldata[ $somekey ][ 2 ]
```

would give `Animals`

Answer (score 0):

If there are simple criteria to access data (e.g. only primary keys), I'd use caching in something like Redis with lifetime to store data where key would be like `table_name:id`.

Comment: I have added examples of the tables and their data.